# MS Access changing linked table to AWS MySQL Db slows down forms/reports

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am new to a new role at a company where they are using MS Access with a MySQL db which is running in server that's physically in our office behind our private network. I have been hired to develop an entire new application to bring the company up to modern standards. As we move features/modules to the new Angular/NodeJs App I am writing, users still need to utilize the UI provided by MS Access to the new production database that will be on AWS Lightsail. 
However, when I change the configurations of Ms Access, OBDC connections to point to the AWS Lightsail MySQL Db, everything(reports especially) in the MS Access UI becomes slower than when it was being pointed to the MySQL Db here in office in-network.

I am going to the "Linked Table Manager" and changing the "Connection String". 
Somewhere I read I should make sure SSLMODE is disabled to remove any performance issues.

> DSN=AWS_Dev;DATABASE=ECSDataTables;PORT=3306;SERVER=IP_ADDRESS;SSLMODE=DISABLED;

I went through the normal "ODBC Data Source Administrator" in Windows and added the MySQL AWS host, user/pass as normal.

I have done extensive research and have found several sources, but none are really helping.

I have been asked not to spend too much time trying to fix/optimize anything in MS Access as my focus should be on the new application, but it's hard to believe that a simple switch of MySQL database can have such impact. In the new Angular/NodeJs application, everything runs very fast, so I know it's not the AWS MySQL db or anything.

Am I missing something, any configurations I should be doing in Ms Access? I have not used VB in about a decade, so I am hoping something can be done without the need of too much technical background in this matter.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the issue is that your local area network (LAN) is about 10 times, or more faster then your internet connection.

Your low cost office network is very likely to be a 1 gig bit network. (100 base T is rare).

However, your internet high speed connection is likely say 10 mbits. So, you going from 1000 to 10 - that is 100 times slower.  So, 3 seconds now becomes 300 seconds.

I mean, with such a slower connection speed, then no surprise should exist here.

What you can do is for any report that is a complex join of client side sql is convert the sql query to a server side view, link to that view. Now use that view as the base source for the report.  And of course existing VBA filers that you always use (right???) to launch a report will now only pull the data it needs down the network pipe. Access reports (or forms) only pull down what you ask - not the whole table. So, any filter you have (use the where clause of the open report command) will be respected. So, you either have to pull less data, or simply find something with a similar speed rating as your local area network (and such high speed internet is rare).

The LAN vs WAN concept and speed issue is outlined in this article:

http://www.kallal.ca//Wan/Wans.html

While the above article is very old, the speed differences of the internet are about 10x  faster today, but so is the local area that's  gone from 100 baseT to 1 gig bit base.

So, things are slower because you are working with a VASTLY slower connection speed. Slower is slower!!!

## Edit

While as noted, access will only pull what you ask, the case where access client does a poor job is sql queries that involve multiple tables - often the client will mess up what it sends server side. As noted, the solution in this case is to adopt views server side. This means you move the client side query that drives the report to a view, and link to that view. You  not gain much performance for a single table query, but for any report based  on complex (multi-table joins), then using a view will force the sql and "join work" to occur sql server side, and this can result in  huge performance gains.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It makes sense regarding the connection speeds as you said....although at this point I have no complex reports running in the new Angular app to test the difference between MS Access and new app. It may in fact take the same amount of time loading in the angular app as it does when I switch MS Access to point to AWS. When I said Angular App runs very fast, it was simple db requests...and simple SELECTs.
I had not considered creating Views. I can definitely try that.

Comment: Is Angular running web or client side? In 100% web based sql queries pulls data from sql server to web server (no slow network in between data pull to client (web server)). Page is THEN the rendered as HTML and sent to the client. A query to return one row from a million row table only pulls 1 record and should work well. Forms opened without a where clause will pull way too many records. How much data you pull in angular as desktop client or Access is a developer choice you need to worry about. Web sites tend to be better because no slow network exists between web server and sql server.

Comment: Angular is for Client side. NodeJS is running as REST API. I am transitioning to GraphQL though for better optimization. 
I tried your recommendation of using a view and seems it's working much faster :) It loaded a query that was previously taking about 10-12 seconds and now it takes about 2 seconds :) It was a pain trying to work with Access though. Thanks again.

Comment: Was not sure if Angular could run server side. Being a client side technology, then issues of pulling data to the client side will be much the same as Access as a client then. As for Access being hard with a linked table, or linked view? Not sure why, but with a simple linked table then you don't even have to write code to layout and launch a report. Access is a simple desktop system, wide used, and 99% of  the reason for Access being so popular is it beyond simple  and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a case where limited knowledge just produces worst results than the expected ones.
Over the years top DBAs just "hate" Ms Access... they just see only problems,issues you name it ...the end sentence is "switch to a real Database engine".
Well this has created a faulty assumption that MsSQL, MySQL,Oracle, PostGreSQL and the rest database engines are somewhat a "magic pill"...you just switch the BE to one of the above DBE and all your problems will get resolved...just like that.
*DBE --Database Engine*  (if you would like to call somewhat else feel free)
**WRONG**
Ms Access follows a different philosophy from the DBE and it does its job damn well given all its shortcoming and the major fact that is a file based DBE.
Switching to another DBE will give amazing performance IF and ONLY IF you respect the fact that you are not working with Access ....just don't treat e.g. MySQL as your file repository and DON'T just link the tables and expect everything to go well...
Want to keep blaming Access ...just switch over to another platform (.NET,PHP,Js , Java...make your pick) ...and do a small application that pulls ALL of your data in a single go like you do with Access .  it will certainly crash or go *Not responding*...
So stop blaming Access ...start reading on how to make the most of two worlds and i am pretty sure that the results will amaze you....but again i must stress out that this is not a "magic pill" solution ...it involves a LOT of work ...planning,data manipulation,normalization,code changes and above all change of philosophy..
I would recommend starting the journey by picking this book : [https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Access-Developers-Guide-Server/dp/0672319446](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672319446) ( i don't want complains about its Old and MsSQL ...just read first and complain later)
Also take a look at an old benchmark alike video i made some years ago : https://www.linkedin.com/posts/tsgiannis_a-small-demo-of-connecting-ms-access-fe-to-activity-6392696633531858944-dsuU
Last but not least....years ago i was making some tests to see what the "magic pill" would do to my company's applications....the simplest test of all...
A simple table with few fields but with around 8 millions records...just display it
Access BE (local)--> It would run in 1-2 seconds...that's fast
Access BE (Network share)--> It would run in a few seconds...not so fast but it was usable
MSSQL BE (linked table)--> somethimes it get the results sometimes it  wouldn't....slow...really slow ..like you make a coffee and go for a small walk.
MySQL BE (linked table)--> it never finished...timeout of "Not Responding"
PostGreSQL BE (linked table)--> it never finished...timeout of "Not Responding"

So stop blaming Access...start working and get amazed....

Comment: Appreciate the insightful comment. I am sure if I knew more about Access, I would not ask the question, but as stated, I was hired to create a new platform for the company and start using tools, technologies that are more up to date. So I am not being asked to learn much regarding Access, but to just make the transition smooth and still having that backward compatibility with Access while I slowly transition all modules/features to the new platform. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not a matter of Access...its a matter of philosophy...i reckon you are Web Developer...so when you pull data from a Database you just pull 50,100...200 at most at a time...(i know about virtual scrolling...the underneath engine just does it for you)...if you would change the Access to pull just the same minimal amount of data it would be blazing fast.